# C# Currency format

Tags: c#, visual-studio

How can i display the following code in Currency formatting? Adding a "c" doesn't work for me.

```
totalLabel.Text = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
```

Comment: Are you only returning one column from your SQL statement?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Currency format for display](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4842332/currency-format-for-display)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
totalLabel.Text = String.Format("{0:C}", cmd.ExecuteScalar());
```

Answer (score 3):

You will probably need to get the value of the ExecuteScalar into an appropriate numerically typed field and then do

```
myAppropriatelyTypeField.ToString("c");
```

Answer (score 1):

The `ExecuteScalar()` method returns a value of type `System.Object` so you need to cast it to number (decimal or double or int).

```
object value = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
if(value!=null)
{
  decimal num=(decimal)value;
  totalLabel.Text=num.ToString("C2")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will help you:

```
decimal total = 0;
object cmdValue = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
if (cmdValue != null && decimal.TryParse(cmdValue.ToString(), out total))
    totalLabel.Text = String.Format("{0:C}", total);
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use string.format for that

```
var stringValue = String.Format("{0:C}", yourValue);
```

hope that helps