# Set currency format using Culture and Globalization

Tags: c#, globalization

I want to format currency at global level. For English currency format will display as $XXX,XXX.XX.
If French then currency format will display as XXX.XXX,XX$. 
How would I set currency format using Culture and Globalization In C#?

Below is my C# code where I am setting the date format:

```
if (Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Name.Equals("fr-CA") || Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Name.Equals("en-CA"))
{
   var currentCulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
   var culture = (CultureInfo)currentCulture.Clone();
   culture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern = "yyyy/MM/dd";
   Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = culture;                            
}
```

Comment: It already works that way.  Why do you want to override it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`NumberFormatInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) via [`CultureInfo.NumberFormat`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.numberformat%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and there are various currency-related properties, including [`CurrencyDecimalSeparator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.currencydecimalseparator%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [`CurrencyPositivePattern`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.currencypositivepattern%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

It looks like you want a positive pattern of 1 - you'll have to look to work out which negative pattern you want.

Answer (score 1):

Check out these two

[MSFT String format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

And From [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9211019/c-sharp-currency-format)

Sample:

```
double value = 12345.6789;
Console.WriteLine(value.ToString("C", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture));
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [Windows.Globalization.NumberFormatting.CurrencyFormatter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.globalization.numberformatting.currencyformatter.aspx) is the preferred way to format currencies. This class is available as of Windows 8 and can be used for Desktop or Windows Store applications. You specify the currency to be formatted separately from the language rules for display.