# C# currency format not working

Tags: c#, formatting

I've a console application with the following:

```
var value = 999999;
System.Console.WriteLine("Price {0:c}", value);

// Prints: Price ? 999.999,00
// Expecting: Price € 999.999,00
```

The line below prints **Price $ 999.999,00**

```
System.Console.WriteLine("Price {0}", value.ToString("c", new CultureInfo("en-US")));
```

But this line:

```
System.Console.WriteLine("Price {0}", value.ToString("c", new CultureInfo("fr-BE")));
```

Prints **?** instead of **€**

What's wrong with the code?

Comment: Prints where?  In a control that doesn't support extended ASCII or Unicode characters?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is nothing wrong in the code assuming your default culture is supposed to print euro. However you seems to be running the program in a console window either directly or through VS launch. The default code page that is used is 437 that can't display the euro symbol. You have to change it to one that can, for example 1252.

```
C:\>chcp
Active code page: 437

C:\>chcp 1252
Active code page: 1252

C:\>\Full\Path\To\Your\Program.Exe
€ 9.999,00
```

Now if you run your program you should see something different. If you are using the default font (Raster Fonts) it would still not display the euro symbol correctly. Change it to Lucida Console and the program should work as expected.

[image: Command Prompt Menu]
[image: Command Prompt Properties]

If you want to control this from the program, add appropriate encoding

```
//Console.OutputEncoding = Encoding.Default;
//Console.OutputEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
```

Comment: Active code page: 850, changed the font to Lucida Console but still not working

Comment: @Stacked, start with 1252 not 850.

Comment: Changing the current OutputEndcoding "Western European (DOS)" to Unicode (UTF-8) solved the issue:
System.Console.OutputEncoding = Encoding.UTF8; Thanks amit_g

Comment: I just wrote Console.OutputEncoding = Encoding.Default; and Console.OutputEncoding = Encoding.UTF8; in Program.cs file, it works for me. No other things did not require for me.

Answer (score 0):

Use [decimal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/693372/what-is-the-best-data-type-to-use-for-money-in-c) instead of int.

```
public class TestDecimalFormat 
{
    static void Main () 
    {
        decimal x = 0.999m;
        decimal y = 9999999999999999999999999999m;
        Console.WriteLine("My amount = {0:C}", x);
        Console.WriteLine("Your amount = {0:C}", y);
    }
}
```

Comment: Capital C instead of lowercase?

Answer (score 0):

First, 
`var int value = 999999;` 
isn't right.

it can be either

```
var value = 999999;
or 
int value = 999999;
```

Second,
Whether or not it prints € or $ or some other currency symbol will depend on your current culture.

e.g.

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var value = 999999;
        System.Console.WriteLine("Price {0:c}", value);
    }
}
```

Gives me the output

```
Price $999,999.00
```

To specify the currency symbol, we can also do the following

```
var numberFormatInfo = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat;
numberFormatInfo = (NumberFormatInfo) numberFormatInfo.Clone();
numberFormatInfo.CurrencySymbol = "€";
Console.WriteLine(string.Format(numberFormatInfo, "{0:c}", value));
```

Comment: Sorry for the "var int" caused by copy/paste, code is correct and compiles. I'm expecting the same result as you but doesn't work for me.

Comment: Tested it but doesn't help :(

Answer (score 0):

According to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4842350) you could modify your code as follows:

```
Console.WriteLine("Price: " + value.ToString("C", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US")));
```

Add your CultureInfo accordingly.