# How can I show currency symbol in a label in c#?

Tags: c#

I am new to c# and I am using windows forms.

Anyone knows how can I show currency symbol in a `label`.
for example:

```
double test = 2.5;
lable1.text = test.Tostring();
```

The result will show 2.5 but I want to show it as £2.5

Please help me how to do that. Thank you

Comment: Use the Currency format see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4842332/currency-format-for-display

Answer (score 5, accepted):

String.Format("{0:C}",test); or test.ToString("C"); should do the trick...

Comment: Yes, good call; string formatting is culture specific; make sure you are using en-GB (which I guess you will be if you are looking for the pound Stirling symbol). Just be careful if you deploy to servers hosted outside the UK that have a different default...

Answer (score 1):

Use string formats like this:

```
double test = 2.5;
lable1.text = test.ToString("£#.#")
```

Just in case you want to display the decimals upto 2 places, you could use something like:

```
lable1.text = test.ToString("£#.##")
```