# Add extra ,00 by number if nothing is left "," or "."

Tags: c#

Where my problem lies is if a user writes 200 then it makes a mistake.

But that error only because I have for example written 200.

I have tried different things that have led to it approving only the number 200 if it is.

My Models:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Money")]
[RegularExpression(@"\d+(\.\d{1,2})?", ErrorMessage = "Error")]
[Range(0, 99999.99, ErrorMessage ="Error")]
[DataType(DataType.Text)]
[Display(Name = "Money")]
public string Pay { get; set; }
```

in my CompaniesController i get the value from "Pay"

```
decimal PayValue = model.Pay.ToString().PayValue();
```

And thus, in PayValue, I have done so that it divides the price in proportion to having to throw "," in between two numbers.

```
public static decimal PayValue(this string str)
    {
        string[] pay;
        pay = str.ToString().Split('.');
        return Convert.ToDecimal(pay[0] + "," + pay[1]);
    }
```

Here I would like it to run through and be successful.

- Error here: **200**
- Error here: **20000**

Thus, I would like if a customer writes the two numbers oven over then it must itself add **,00** only if nothing **,00** is add after the whole number.

Code fails if I only write 200, What I want it to be is that it must go through and even add ,00 after the number.

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly you are just wanting to show the amount formatted as currency? If so check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4842332/currency-format-for-display

Comment: Why convert to `decimal`? Why replace `'.'` with `','`?

Comment: This is a case where I would recommend a unit test as the universal language. It's very, very hard to understand the problem you're trying to solve. But if you expressed it as a failing unit test (maybe a parameterized test) then there would be no barriers.

Comment: Thanks @akaBase It helped solve the problem for me.