# Getting the value of a pound sign (£) in JSON returns a question mark (?)

Tags: c#, json

I am trying to get the value of a key in my JSON data however I am receiving a question mark as response.

My `config.json` file:

```
{
    currency_sign: "£"
}
```

My code:

```
public static void readConfig()
{
    var file = File.ReadAllText("config.json");
    var file2 = JObject.Parse(file);

    string currency = file2.SelectToken("currency_sign").Value<string>();
    Console.WriteLine("Currency: " + currency);
}
```

Output of my code:

```
Currency: ?
```

I have also tried encoding the string:

```
byte[] bytes = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(currency);
currency = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
```

However the output was exactly the same.

Why is my code returning `?` instead of `£` and how can I fix this?

Comment: Would specifying encoding parameter such as `Encoding.UTF8` for `File.ReadAllText` help?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Currency format for display](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4842332/currency-format-for-display)

Comment: Please see https://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html. Then [specify the encoding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readalltext?view=netcore-3.1#System_IO_File_ReadAllText_System_String_System_Text_Encoding_) of your file in the `ReadAllText` call.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try setting console output encoding to UTF8 before your `Console.WriteLine` statement:

```
Console.OutputEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
```

Comment: @Fluffy what OS? What system language?

Comment: @Fluffy also what output do you get with simple `Console.WriteLine("£")`?

Comment: Windows 10 Pro, C# .Net Console Application

Comment: I'm guessing the value itself has to be encoded as JSON may be having trouble reading it.

Comment: Also I have tested this in Python, the only difference is that it outputted `£` correctly.

Comment: @Fluffy try writing the whole file/line with  `currency_sign` to console.

Comment: Sure, I did `Console.WriteLine(file2);` and the output was: `{
    "currency_sign": "?"
}`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215958/discussion-between-guru-stron-and-fluffy).

Comment: It is unhelpful for future readers that this answer is marked as accepted, given that it cannot be correct due to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62375592/getting-the-value-of-a-pound-sign-%c2%a3-in-json-returns-a-question-mark#comment110317032_62375672. If you found an actual solution in the chat, please edit your answer to reflect that.